# Number of cases in server relaying problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

There are 4 servers namely X,Y,Z,W. A message after being received by one server is relayed to another server. Find the possible number of cases where a message originating from one server after seven relays reaches the same server.

One possible example of this-
W->X->W->Y->Z->X->Y->W

Attempt->
Lets say there are 8 empty places and we need to fill them appropriately. Say, the first place is occupied by W. The last place is also occupied by W. The remaining 6 places can be filled by $3^6$ ways.
So total cases- $4*3^6$

Comment: This way, you are counting sequences ending with -W-W although they are forbidden. For example the number of admissible sequences W-anything-anything-W is 6, not 9 as your formula would predict.

Comment: Then what is the way out?

Comment: One can count the number of admissible sequences of $n$ relays starting with W and ending with W, call it $A_n$, and the number of admissible sequences of $n$ relays starting with W and ending with anything else than W, call it $B_n$. Then you are after $4A_8$ and you know that$A_1=1$, $B_1=0$, $A_n=B_{n-1}$ and $A_n+B_n=3^{n-1}$, right? This gives you every $A_n$, hence you are done. Can you proceed?